# Serialization member by member

Tags: c++, templates, serialization, template-specialization

I've implemented a `template<typename T> Serializer` that works on any *trivially copyable* object of type `T`, just serializing `sizeof(T)` bytes.

Then I've implemented a couple of (partial) specializations for other types of interest, like `std::vector<T>` and `std::bacis_string<T>`. For other types, I trigger a `static_assert(is_trivially_copyable<T>::type, "Unsupported type");`.

This is not what I want, because I want to avoid serializing, for example, types with **naked pointers**, like:

```
struct C_style_vector{
    size_t size;
    int* ptr;
};
```

For such kind of types, I assume that the user will define an ad hoc specialization. Conversely, as far as now my `Serializer` doesn't work with a type like this:

```
struct Simple_type{
    double d;
    std::vector<int> v;
};
```

even though every member of `Simple_type` is serializable by my class.

So, how can I *catch types with naked pointers*?
And how can I tell my serializer to serialize types composed only by serializable members, *serializing it member by member*?

Comment: If you've ever wondered why there is such a mammoth amount of wood behind the [`boost::serialization`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) arrow, wonder no longer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not actually simple and cannot be done in C++, without some users additions, since there is no reflection in C++.

You can use something like boost::fusion, but user should use fusion sequences in this case. The best way is that uses boost::serialization I think, user MUST provide `serialize/deserialize` functions for own types.

Example with fusion.

```
template<bool Value, typename Next, typename Last>
struct is_serializable_impl
{
private:
   static const bool cvalue = !boost::is_pointer<
   typename boost::remove_reference<
   typename boost::fusion::result_of::deref<Next>::type>::type>::value;
public:
   static const bool value = Value && is_serializable_impl<
   cvalue, typename boost::fusion::result_of::next<Next>::type, Last>::value;
};

template<bool Value, typename Last>
struct is_serializable_impl<Value, Last, Last>
{
   static const bool value = Value;
};

template<typename T>
struct is_serializable :
is_serializable_impl<true, typename boost::fusion::result_of::begin<T>::type,
   typename boost::fusion::result_of::end<T>::type>
{
};

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct serializer;

template<typename T>
struct serializer<T,
typename boost::enable_if<typename 
boost::fusion::traits::is_sequence<T>::type>::type>
{
   static_assert(is_serializable<T>::value, "Not serializable");
};
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40f6e9e697ad145d)