# How to serialize a struct with a string field in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a data structure called `Message` and I need to turn it into a series of chars to send it via the network. The issue is the struct also contains a string field, and this field does not get cast correctly. I'm new to C++ and C programming, so I didn't realize this would be an issue. Here is the code

```
typedef struct {
  int id;
  string content;
} Message;

Message msg;
....
send_message(reinterpret_cast<char*>(msg));
```

Comment: there is (atleast,  should) no `c` _and_ `c++`, IMHO, it's `c` __or__ `c++`. Choose yours. :-)

Comment: Why don't you just write a function that creates the string representation of your structure? Or a method of that structure that does it.

Comment: General rule of thumb: `reinterpret_cast` is the wrong tool.

Comment: You can't serialize complex class types like `std::string` or `std::vector` this way. Look out for a good serialization library like [`boost::serialization`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) or [google protobu](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/)f.

Comment: You can use regular socket api's to serialize ,send and receive .

Comment: string is not POD data, so you need to serialize it somehow. For good solution try any serialization tools. 
By hands easiest way to serialize string is to write size of array and next char array with string data.

Answer (score 4):

At work, I did a class with template methods to serialize (into a char array) basic types and some std types, like vector and string.

```
class MySerializer{
public:
    // serialize operator
    template<typename T>
    friend MySerializer& operator<<( MySerializer&, const T&);

    // deserialize operator
    template<typename T>
    friend MySerializer& operator>>( MySerializer&, T& );
private:
    std::vector<unsigned char> v;
};
```

Then, if you need to serialize custom types, you can add specializations as needed. For basic types, you can just `copy` them byte to byte into `v`. Custom types need a few more work. Fore example, let's see how to serialize an `std::string`.

For this use case, you can look at `std::string` as a pair of a`size_t` where is stored the size of the `string` and a `char*` that points to string's chars. When you serialize a string, you could put its [`string::size()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/size/), casted for example to an `uint32_t` or `uint64_t`, into the serializer and then copy into the serializer `string::size()` characters starting from [`string::c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/). When you will deserialize, first you need to read string's size from the serializer, and then put the proper number of chars into your output `string`.

You may be interested also in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28500822/serialization-member-by-member) of mine.

Comment: How would you use this?